# Paypal-credit smart payment button not showing up

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Paypal is now offering smart buttons that show (when allowed) additional buttons besides the simple checkout button.

I'm trying to add the Paypal-Credit (previously known as Bill-me-later) option to our web-app, but following the code example in the Paypal docs wasn't enough to make it show up.

I've made sure that the client-ID I'm using is from an account in the UK (one of the supported countries of Paypal-credit) and had my client who also lives there view the page and it still doesn't show up.

Users from countries that aren't supported by the service will not be able to see the button regardless of the code.

Worth to mention that neither the sandbox client-ID nor the production one worked for this case.

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ASNhOuArXbdfbcCioO8c161vsapHmjjeX03Yn9FYdxfSOF2MbW8FEtepQBtXF1XD0Xvs3WTPQrvDXzH-&currency=GBP"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
      layout: 'horizontal', fundingicons: 'true'
    },
    funding: {
      allowed: [paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT]
    }
  }).render('body');
</script>
```

The expected result is two buttons: "Paypal" and "Credit" next to it as shown in the docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/customize-button/#multiple-button-layout

The result is the single default "Paypal" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the currency to USD

Ref: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/Using-Pay-Pal-Credit-to-purchase-items-from-England-GBP/td-p/1403038

Comment: Unfortunately changing the currency didn't fix the issue. If you've attempted the fix on the code I've posted, could you kindly share it? Here's a fiddle if you'd like to test things quickly: https://jsfiddle.net/0rnhd5k1/

Comment: I had tested it already. From a US IP, currency=GBP showed no credit button, currency=USD showed the credit button, without any other changes to the code.

Comment: OMG... so PayPal shows different styles depending on IP location even in sandbox... fml

Comment: ?? buyer country detection is an essential feature, if you need to force a country during testing, use the documented `buyer-country` query string parameter, which is for sandbox only

Answer (score 0):

**This will work.**

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>paypal.Button.render({ ....
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mzvarik/c24r3pkt/

However I am so confused and upset with PayPal that I have no idea why.